# Error in installing an extension via setup wizard in Magento admin 2.1.7

Tags: extensions, marketplace, magento-2.1.7, web-setup-wizard

We are trying to install a `fooman/emailattachments-m2 extension` ( or any extension) from Magento marketplace using `system -> web setup wizard ->component manager`. It successfully completed the `readiness check and backup steps` during installation, The maintenance mode also successfully enabled for frontend.

During the next step (new purchase status page) it started installation and show the text **update pending**.

**When we access the frontend after 2 mins (After next cron job ran) the maintenance mode will automatically disabled, the extension also successfully installed and our site also working fine.**

The `Console.log` also shows there is no error everything working fine.

We have noticed the update flag files (`.update_in_progress.flag, .update_error.flag`) also not generated in var folder.

**Since, The setup wizard page (new purchase status page) still showing the following error.**

The buttons also not working (Roll Back , Next buttons), Even the menu links also not working on this page.

**We have checked in browser console there is a error like angularjs is not defined.**

Kindly anyone suggest me to resolve the issue, Thanks.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idWHg.png)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove all .files in `/www/html/magento/var` folder. I had same issue and I solved doing that:

[image: console]

```
sudo rm -rf .update_status.txt
sudo rm -rf .update_queue.json
sudo rm -rf .setup_cronjob_status
sudo rm -rf .type.json
sudo rm -rf .update_cronjob_status
```

Answer (score -1):

By removing (but backing up first) `**update_error.flag**.` Then logged out and in again from the Magento Admin panel.